# Validate JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How do I validate `JTextField` for a personal number? For example, I would like it to validate something formatted like `841017-4567`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) and [MaskFormatter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/newJFormattedTextFieldnewMaskFormatter.htm).

```
JFormattedTextField phoneField = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("######-####"));
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I think he was confused because I edited the question to fix some grammar, so it probably looked like I answered my own question.