# Check if jTextField input is an int or a string

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, jtextfield

My code:

```
name = jTextFieldName.getText();
admin = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldAdmin.getText());
anal = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldAnalytical.getText());
creat = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldCreative.getText());
finish = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldFinisher.getText());

persons.addPerson(name, admin, anal, creat, finish);

persons.savePersons();
```

I want to make sure that name is a string and that admin, anal, creat and finish are ints between 0 and 30. I'm thinking that I should use try-catch, but I don't know exactly how to use it in this context. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Write down a separate method to validate all the values and only then add them.

Comment: You could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749521/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926745/validate-jtextfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try catch isn't a bad way to handle this:

```
try {
    name = jTextFieldName.getText();
    admin = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldAdmin.getText());
    anal = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldAnalytical.getText());
    creat = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldCreative.getText());
    finish = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldFinisher.getText());

    persons.addPerson(name, admin, anal, creat, finish);

    persons.savePersons();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // One of the integer fields failed to parse. Do something to alert the user.
}
```

You can then also put some bounds checking in the try part. e.g.

```
if (admin < 0 || admin > 30) {
    // Problem. Alert the user.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a `JSpinner` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `if-else` which statisfies condition or ask user to input again if required.

ex -

```
if(admin<0 || admin>30){
  // ask user to input again.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `InputVerifier` for `JTextField`, like below

```
public class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
        // Validate input here, like check int by try to parse it using Integer.parseInt(text), and return true or false
    }
}

// Set input verifier to the text field
jTextField.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
```